# Manipulating popover to contain text and html in different div inside data-content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap to implement popover. I know that I can pass html: true during invocation if I need to have data-content title rendered as html. But if I have different div inside data-content or title and I want different behaviors for those div(some to be rendered as html and some as text), then how should I implement it.
eg. :

```
data-content=
"<div>
<div id='RenderAsText'><b>Rendering As Text</b></div>
<div id='RenderAsHtml'><b>Rendering As Html</b></div>
</div>"
```

And result should look like below:

```
<b>Rendering As Text</b>
```

**Rendering As Html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event bootstrap popover [shown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-events) and jquery function [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to render content as text:

```
$(function () {
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover().on("shown.bs.popover", function () {
        var html = $('#RenderAsText').html();
        $('#RenderAsText').text(html);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6sbxu55/)